# How to check for the msoledbsql driver installed in the system (in Delphi 5)

Tags: delphi, driver

My intention is to use the new Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (msoledbsql) for database connection in Delphi 5 if it is installed in the system. If it is not installed than I am using old driver (sqloledb).
My question is: What would be the proper way to check for the driver installed in the system?
I guess it has somethink to do with Registry check and also some dlls existing in the folder. I know how to chek for dlls but I am not sure about the Registry.

Comment: Note that MSOLEDBSQL (and SQLNCLI11) do some things differently than sqloledb. We had some issues where it calls sp_describe_first_result_set instead of the deprecated SET FMTONLY ON method to get result column structures. When used with some insert queries that used select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as part of the same statement (using `qry.Open()` instead of `qry.ExecSQL`  it failed on some tables with complex triggers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ADODB.GetProviderNames()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.Win.ADODB.GetProviderNames)

This will populate a TStrings with a list of all installed providers. I assume it was added when ADODB.pas was first created for Delphi 5 in 1999, but I have no way to confirm that.

Here's one I prepared earlier...

```
Providers := TStringList.Create;
try
  GetProviderNames(Providers);
  if Providers.IndexOf('MSOLEDBSQL') >= 0 then
    ConnectionString := 'Provider=MSOLEDBSQL.1;'
  else
    ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;';
finally
  Providers.Free;
end;
```

if it isn't, look at [Check if Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Index Server (aka Provider=MSIDXS) is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748495/check-if-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-index-server-aka-provider-msidxs-is-ins) for a C# example. It is fairly simple COM handling

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need. Somehow I missed the same answer in the linked question. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately,  the best answer  isn't  the best answer

Comment: I meant first answer